# How to see that we've reached the end of the data for a socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

Is there something the client needs to do in order to flag that "This is the end?"

For example, I have the following server running:

```
import socket, sys
while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('', 5500))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected by', addr)
    data = b''
    while True:
        data_chunk = conn.recv(10)
        data += data_chunk
        if not data: break
    # How do I get here so I can echo the message *at the end* ?
    # conn.send(b'Done. What you sent was: %s' % data)
```

And I have the following client code:

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('sandbox2.myip.com', 5500))
client_socket.send(b'select * from table')
# Now, what to do so that I can get the final message from he server?
```

When I do the connection though, this is what it shows:

```
sampleDB$ python listener.py
Connected by ('99.51.149.29', 63352)
```

I can confirm that the data `data_chunks` are being received, but then it just seems to hang at this part right here:

```
data_chunk = conn.recv(10)
```

Is there something I need to do in the client (or the server?) to flag that "This is the end of the transmission, so `conn.recv()` doesn't just hang indefinitely?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is - yes - that's what you need to do. Or, the client can just disconnect in which case the *recv()* will return an empty bytes object. The more complex answer is that you should implement a protocol whereby the client sends a network independent integer value as a preamble to the actual data that indicates how much data is going to be sent. In that way the server reads the byte count first (known length) then calls *recv()* with that value

Comment: Yes, you need and END_OF_DATA on both client and server sides.  But really, you need an additional protocol layer.  Eg. you want the connection to remain open, waiting for the next request, rather the open/close connection on each request.  As well as a QUIT command.  Read up on TDS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example of a socket based client/server protocol that implements the strategy described in my comment:

```
import socket
import threading
from struct import pack, unpack

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 7070
FORMAT = ('!Q', 8)
MSG = '''The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea 
   In a beautiful pea-green boat, 
They took some honey, and plenty of money, 
   Wrapped up in a five-pound note. 
The Owl looked up to the stars above, 
   And sang to a small guitar, 
"O lovely Pussy! O Pussy, my love, 
    What a beautiful Pussy you are, 
         You are, 
         You are! 
What a beautiful Pussy you are!"'''


def sendbuffer(s, b):
    buffer = pack(FORMAT[0], len(b)) + b
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(buffer):
        offset += s.send(buffer[offset:])


def recvbuffer(s):
    p = s.recv(FORMAT[1], socket.MSG_WAITALL)
    n = unpack(FORMAT[0], p)[0]
    return None if n == 0 else s.recv(n, socket.MSG_WAITALL)


def server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, _ = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while (data := recvbuffer(conn)):
                sendbuffer(conn, data)


def client(msg):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        sendbuffer(s, msg.encode())
        data = recvbuffer(s)
        print(data.decode())
        sendbuffer(s, b'') # kill switch


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=server).start()
    client(MSG)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks so much. A few questions: Why do you send it as a bytearray with `struct` instead of just `b'select * from table'` or sending a string converted to bytes? And second, what about ending the transmission with a `\0` or something instead of doing it fixed-length or such?

Comment: You can certainly end with binary zero but in order to detect that you'd have to call recv() with a length of 1 multiple times. Using the preamble means that you only have to call recv() twice thus making it more efficient. pack() returns a byte object. socket.send() requires a bytes object